# Search in Array of dictionary with multiple keys

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, predicate

I have array of profile class:

```
let foo = [
    [profileClass],
    [profileClass],
    [profileClass],
]
```

Profile class is below :

```
class profileClass: modelclass {
  let name: String
  let severity: String
  let address : String

 init(name: String, severity: String, address: String){
    self.name = name
    self.severity = severity
    self.address = address
  }
}
```

How can i use predicate to perform search option in keys for name and address both.I am using below logic but it only filter from key "name" and it is not predicate.
I wanted to use predicate and search result if string exist in "name" or in "address"

```
guard foo != nil, foo?.count ?? 0 > 0 && searchString != nil  else { return }
    var filteredfoo = foo?[0].modelclass.filter { viewModel -> Bool in
      return viewModel.name.containsIgnoringCase(find: searchString!)
    }
```

Comment: What is that `foo` array, is it really an array of arrays where the inner arrays only contain one element each or is this some kind of typo. Could you please provide a proper example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `|| viewModel.address.containsIgnoringCase(find: searchString!)` in return statement.

So final return would look like this:

```
return viewModel.name.containsIgnoringCase(find: searchString!) || viewModel.address.containsIgnoringCase(find: searchString!)
```

Comment: force unwrap searchString lead to crash